# Reading wrong number of '\n' from csv file

Tags: c, file-io, fread

Function reads csv file, replaces delimiter with null character and counts number of columns and newlines, but returns wrong number of '\n', I have no idea why?? Please help!

Comment near end of code: should be 24643 - actual 24687

**Sample Data:** I manually added the ',' delimiter where necessary to show column changes.

Product,23659,LAUX431GDS X431,Graphic Diagnostic Scan Tool,P,LAUX431GDS,CANDO INTERNATIONAL,Right,OE-level access to Domestic, European and Asian manufacturers, for read/clear codes, live data graphing and recording with bi-directional testing and module coding (separate modules for a 4 channel oscilloscope, ignition analyzer, sensor simulator and multimeter will be available)

Unrivaled speed in the diagmostic access and communication of all vehicle systems and their modules. Wifi-enabled, allowing you access to your favorite websites for troubleshooting advice, charts, and repair information.

One-button update which allows you to update one or more car lines at a time

No need to connect to a PC for updates, all patches and software updates are direct through you subscription each year the tool is updated.

Includes the first year of updates

```
    int getCurrentData(FILE *current){

    int totalChars = 0, colCount = 0, productCount = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL, next = '\0';
    size_t i = 0;

    fseek(current, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t fileSize = ftell(current);
    rewind(current);

    buffer = malloc(fileSize);
    fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, current);

    /*replacing delimiter with null character*/
    for (i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
        if (buffer[i] == ',' && buffer[i+1] != ' '){
            buffer[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    /*finds column and product count*/
    for (i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
        if (buffer[i] == '\0' && productCount == 0 || buffer[i] == '\n' && productCount == 0){
            colCount++;
        }
        if (buffer[i] == '\n' && i < fileSize){
            productCount++;                         /*should be 24643 - actual 24687*/
        }
    }

    return productCount;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the number should be different?

Comment: One problem is that you assume the buffer you read from the file will contain the value `EOF`.

Comment: probably, `fileSize` is incorrect.

Comment: To clarify your question: you're saying that this code returns 24687 when there are only 24643 lines in the file? That it's counting 44 _more_ lines than are actually there?

Comment: Oh by the way, how do you open the file?

Comment: Maybe try opening the file in binary mode instead of text mode, perhaps it's confusing the file size or CR characters are doing something funny

Comment: @woolstar It is a product file, there is a \n at the end of each product line and there are 24643 lines

Comment: You should try to narrow down the problem. Work up with a smaller file or something, to verify that your code is in fact correct. Then try binary-search debugging through your file by trying half, seeing if it's accurate, then trying the other half, and cutting those in half, and repeat.

Comment: Is "Product,23659,... first year of updates" one line of CSV data? Does you data consists of "<li>" or a Unicode character before the word "Unrivaled"?  Is so, is you file UTF8, UTF16?

Comment: @chux  "Product,23659,... first year of updates" is all one line. The data does have <li> before Unrivaled. I dont know how to check the encoding is, but it is saved in excel 2007.

Comment: Your "should be" is 24643 and "actual" 24687.  The 24687 is from your code.  How did you determine the 24643?  If that is the number of rows in Excel, be aware a cell can have multiple lines.

Comment: Great point @chux. I think the sample data I posted contains one of them.

Comment: On second thought the <li> might cause the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Number of issues

1. The main problem is the replacing delimiter loop may replace `\n` with `\0`.
2. Minor: `long fileSize` should be `size_t fileSize`.
3. `if (next != EOF){`  should be deleted.
4. Minor: `buffer = malloc(fileSize + 1);` should be `buffer = malloc(fileSize);`
5. The replace loop is messed up

   ```
   size_t fileSize = ftell(current);
   ...
   buffer = malloc(fileSize);           // later add error checking
   fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, current); // later add error checking
   /*replacing delimiter with null character*/
   for (size_t i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
     if (buffer[i] == ',') {
       // Not sure why OP has (buffer[i+1] != ' ')?  Maybe \n was originally meant
       if ((i+1) >= filesize) || ((buffer[i+1] != ' ') && (buffer[i+1] != '\n'))) {
         buffer[i] = '\0';
       // Or rather than the above if(), maybe something simple:
       buffer[i] = '\0';
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Code not tested - sorry not enough time.

Comment: I use (ch == ',' && next != ' ') due to there being commas in the csv data. It is the only way I know how to separate the delimiter and the csv data. Also, I have fixed issues 2,3 & 4 that you mentioned, but still getting incorrect number of \n. Any other ideas?? thanks!

Comment: @TinMan Specify what exactly do you mean by _delimiter_?  The comma, the space, some combination, something else?

Comment: @TinMan Does the CSV data that contains commas, have distinguishing attributes - like being bracketed with quote ('"') marks?   How about some sample lines of your challenging CSV data?

Comment: The delimiter is just a comma followed by no space, I'll post some data now.